# Authorising users to view files PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, authorization

I have a login system that is fully functional and I keep the user logged in by their ID in a Session Variable $_SESSION['user_id'].

I would like to use that ID to authorise them to view certain files.

I know I can use a MySQL database to store whether they are authorised to see a certain file and then check their ID against the database when it is accessed via a web page, e.g. file.php with a container on the page, however how do I stop someone from finding out what the URL of the file is (e.g. /files/file.pdf) and navigating to that in their browser and viewing it that way?

I know there has to be a way but my knowledge is obviously limited.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Connor Wyatt

Comment: Place your files outside the public html area.

Comment: That works? How do I link to them on a web page? By using the server root and then finding the path?

Comment: If you write it as an answer I will tick it by the way

Comment: `$file = "/var/user/you/outside_folder/file.xxx";` type of thing.

Comment: You're welcome; it has been done.

Comment: you can use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) from your script if the user is authorized

Comment: @bansi Very good point. I will add that and an example from there. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***As per OP's request.***

Place your files outside the public html area.

`$file = "/var/user/you/outside_folder/file.xxx";` type of thing.

---

> *"you can use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) from your script if the user is authorized"*

Bansi's suggestion of using [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is a good method.

As per an example on that page:

```
$filename = "file.csv";
$filepath = "/path/to/file/" . $filename;
```

---

From example #1

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

where `$file = 'monkey.gif';` can be modified to read as:

```
$file = '/var/user/you/outside_folder/monkey.gif';
```